# iAd in IOS8 tab bar application with a toolbar; Proper stacking for Apple Store acceptance?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, iad

In my application, I have a tab bar architecture.  When a tab button is tapped, a transition to a viewcontroller that has an iAd banner view at the bottom, and a containerview stretching from the top of the view to the top of the banner.  The container view shows a collectionviewcontroller.  Basically, the viewcontroller is a wrapper that simply provides space for the banner.  There are several different collection views that could be displayed based on tab bar touches...

Today, I needed to add a toolbar to a collectionviewcontroller, and I do not know where the iAd banner should be placed...

This seems like a reasonable stack, but my use of a containerview will not support it...
iAd Banner
ToolBar
TabBar

Since I am wrapping my collectionviewcontroller with its toolbar, inside the viewcontroller with the banner, I have the following stack:

ToolBar
iAd Banner
TabBar

Apple's docs don't specify the location when you have both a tab bar and tool bar.  I would appreciate your help in learning whether both alternatives would be accepted by Apple's store.

Comment: It's very, very unlikely that Apple will reject an app for UI reasons.

Comment: The placement of your iAd banner is completely up to you. Could you add a screenshot of the UI to your question?

Comment: Hi Guys,  I saw that my posted question changed my stack of items to a line of items.  Basically, they are stacked from the top, down as you read from the left to the right.  Apple's human interface guidelines doc says that when you have a "Toolbar or tab bar", the banner must be placed "directly above the bottom bar".  Which is not very explicit and doesn't cover the case when you have both a tab bar and a tool bar.